# .sh line endings

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

so i have .sh file with commands
For example

```
sudo ssh -i '/media/goldstar/Project/!keys/test4.pem' ubuntu@stereolife.website "sudo chmod +x ~/stereoserver/stereoserver"
sudo ssh -i '/media/goldstar/Project/!keys/test4.pem' ubuntu@stereolife.website "sudo ~/stereoserver/stereoserver -s start"
```

Every line have standart ending with '\r\n' symbols

When .sh file executes \r symbol appends to each line

Is there way execute .sh file with \r\n line endings?

P.S. visual studio code can save line endings with \n only
God save Microsoft!

Comment: It sounds like a Windows vs Linux line endings issue. Two things here, 1. Why write ssh in you bash script when you can just execute the entire script with sudo, 2. Linux should handle the line endings e.g. if you create the script with 'vim bashscript.sh' or 'nano bashscript.sh'.

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt, i wrote my script in gedit in ubuntu =\ why standart linux gui editor puts \r\n?

Comment: That sounds weird! I had the same problem when running code written in windows on the windows subsystem for linux. Making a git push in windows, and then a git pull in the subsystem fixed the problem. I guess you will have to go to the gedit settings and change the default lineendings :)

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt 6 to 1 half-dozen to another, some people like to elevate permissions when necessary using sudo in a script, others run under sudo and drop permissions when necessary (interactive, vs non-interactive scripts usually). As for op, can you post the output rather than just paraphrasing the output

Comment: FYI `gedit` has a drop down option to choose the line endings (Unix/Mac/Windows) at the bottom of the "Save" dialog. I don't know why it would be necessary to execute `ssh` as root anyhow - the only reason I can think to do so would be if it needed access to keys from `/root/.ssh`, which doesn't appear to be the case here since you are passing it a PEM keyfile explicitly.